# Is it possible to fetch information from TYPO3 backend to TYPO3 FE?

Tags: typo3

I am new to TYPO3 backend development. I wanted to know if it is possible to fetch some of the backend information from the TYPO3 tables to the page?

[copied from comment:]

I am getting the error - `Core: Error handler (BE): PHP Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in/Users/Meghna/Sites/typo3_8.7/typo3/sysext/backend/Classes/Form/InlineStackProcessor.php line 225.`

I tried the following code in the setup section of template:

```
page = PAGE 
page.10 = TEXT 
page.10.value = HELLO WORLD! 
page.10.marks.OUTPUT=TEXT 
page.10.marks.LEFT=CONTENT 
page.10.marks.LEFT{ 
    table = tt_content 
    select.orderBy =sorting 
    select.where= colPos=1
} 
page.10.marks.LEFT.renderObj < tt_content
```

Comment: Your question as it stands is not really useful and you won't get an answer. Please add more details and explicitly ask for specific things.

Comment: I am getting the error - Core: Error handler (BE): PHP Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in/Users/Meghna/Sites/typo3_8.7/typo3/sysext/backend/Classes/Form/InlineStackProcessor.php line 225. I tried the following code in the setup section of template: 
 page = PAGE 
page.10 = TEXT 
 page.10.value = HELLO WORLD! 
page.10.marks.OUTPUT=TEXT 
page.10.marks.LEFT=CONTENT
page.10.marks.LEFT{
table = tt_content 
select.orderBy =sorting 
select.where= colPos=1}
page.10.marks.LEFT.renderObj < tt_content

Comment: Please add the code to your question, not as comment.

Answer (score 0):

I still cannot figure out what your question in detail is, so here some remarks:

1. You get a PHP warning which is not urgent. You should be aware of PHP errors. Warnings can happen often.
2. The warning has something to do with a form element. Do you have form content elements on the page?
3. Your TypoScript code looks okay, but it's outdated. Please take a look to the FLUIDTEMPLATE TypoScript object: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/Fluidtemplate/Index.html